# Continuity of support functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, continuity, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $X$ be a normed space(not necessarily Banach) and let $G$ be a $w^*-$compact subset of $X^*,$ the dual space of $X.$ Consider the function $f:X\to \Bbb R$ defined by

$$f(x)= \max_{g^*\in G}\{\langle g^*,x\rangle\}.$$ Is $f$ continuous? If not, what about lower semicontinuous? Could you present a example of a discontinuous $f$?

I can prove that if $X$ is Banach the function is Lipschitz(by using the Uniform Boundedness Theorem). However, in the general case I am still curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Is $f(x)$ well-defined?**

Yes, if $G$ is not empty. Let $x\in X$ be given.
The function $\psi_x:X^*\to\mathbb R$, $x^*\mapsto \langle x^*, x\rangle$
is continuous from the $w^*$-topology of $X^*$ to $\mathbb R$.
Therefore, the image of $G$ under $\psi_x$ is compact.
Because the maximum of each non-empty compact subset of $\mathbb R$ exists and is real-valued,
$f(x)$ is well-defined.

**Is $f$ continuous?**

I think I found a counterexample.

Let $X=\ell^2_0$,
which is the subspace of $\ell^2$ which consists of sequences with only finitely many nonzero entries.
Clearly, $X$ is not a Banach space and $\ell^2$ is its dual space.
We set
$$
G := \{\sqrt{n}e_n : n\in\mathbb N\} \cup \{0\}\subset X^*.
$$
Then it can be shown that $G$ is a $w*$-compact subset of $X^*$
(I can fill in the details if requested).

Let us show that $f$ is not continuous.
Let $x_n:=n^{-1/2}e_n$ be a sequence in $\ell^2_0$.
Clearly, $x_n\to 0$.
However, we have $f(x_n)=\langle \sqrt{n} e_n,n^{-1/2}e_n\rangle = 1$
and $f(0)$, but not $f(x_n)\to f(0)$.
Therefore $f$ is not continuous.

This seems to contradict the answer of @Red shoes.

**Is $f$ lower semicontinuous?**

Yes, $f$ should be lower semicontinuous.
This is because of the arguments in the answer of @Red shoes.

**Under what conditions on $G$ is $f$ continuous?**

It can be shown that $f$ is continuous if and only if $G$ is bounded
(and if and only if $f$ is continuous at $0$).

First, suppose that $G$ is bounded.
Then it can be seen that $f$ is locally bounded.
Since $f$ is also lower semicontinuous it follows that $f$ is continuous.

Now, suppose that $f$ is continuous at $0$.
As we can see in the question
[Unbounded subdifferential of a convex functional](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3575967/unbounded-subdifferential-of-a-convex-functional/), 
this implies that $\partial f(0)$ is bounded.
Now we claim that $G\subset \partial f(0)$ holds.
Indeed, for each $g^*\in G$ we have
$ f(x)-f(0) = f(x) \geq \langle g^*, x \rangle $
and therefore $g^*\in\partial f(0)$.
Since $\partial f(0)$ is bounded this implies that $G$ has to be bounded, too.

Comment: thanks for the comment. With your answer of my previous question, I was able to show that the functional is always l.s.c, and it is continuous if and only if $G$ is norm bounded. If you write that answer I will award the bounty :)

Comment: @JohnD I added this result to my answer. I also included a comment why $f$ is well-defined.

Comment: there you go. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is continuous.

The $ epi f$ is intersection of all closed half space in the form $\{(x , \alpha) \in X \times R : ~~ \langle g^* , x \rangle  \leq \alpha \}$ where $g^* \in G$.

This shows the *\epi f* is closed and convex and Hence $f$ is convex and lower semicontinuous  which implies $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I don't agree with you here. We have $$epi f=\cup_{\alpha\in \Bbb R} \cap_{g^* \in G}\{(x,\alpha) \in X\times \Bbb R: \langle g^*,x\rangle \leq \alpha\},$$ so the argument that $epi f$ is closed woud not be necessarily true.

Comment: @Magnusseen  look at what you wrote,   does that make sense at all !   You shouldn't take union on $\alpha$ 

We have
$$epi f=  \cap_{g^* \in G}\{(x,\alpha) \in X\times \Bbb R: \langle g^*,x\rangle \leq \alpha\},$$

Comment: Ups, you were right, I don't know what I was thinking. However, I checked the statement: $f$ is convex + $f$ l.s.c $\Longrightarrow$ $f$ continuous, and in the proof they assume that $X$ is Banach in order to apply Baire's Category Theorem. Could you provide a reference where this assumption is not needed? See for example Proposition 0.7 b) in http://www.mat.unimi.it/users/libor/AnConvessa/continuity.pdf

Comment: Another approach  Convex + Local bounded  implies continuity in any normed space.  @Magnusseen

Comment: Of course, that was my initial approach, but I don't see the local boundedness.  @Red Shoes