# Unbounded subdifferential of a convex functional

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, banach-spaces, non-convex-optimization

Let $X$ be a normed space, $\bar{x} \in X,$ and $f: X\to \Bbb R$ be a convex functional that is continuous at $\bar{x}.$ It is well known that in this case, $\partial f(\bar{x})$ is nonempty and $w^*$- compact. In particular, if $X$ is Banach, it follows that $\partial f(\bar{x})$ is (dual norm) bounded as a consequence of the Uniform Boundedness Theorem. Hence the question:

Does there exists a normed space $X,$ a point $\bar{x}\in X,$ and a convex functional $f: X \to \Bbb R$ continuous at $\bar{x}$ such that $\partial f(\bar{x})$ is (dual norm) unbounded??

Of course, if it exists, $X$ cannot be Banach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always bounded in this case.
If you want an unbounded subgradient then you need a function that is
not continuous at $\bar x$.

If $f$ is continuous at $\bar x$, there exists
a $\delta>0$ such that
$f(\bar x+y)<f(\bar x)+1$ for all $y$ with $\|y\| < \delta$.

Let $\xi\in\partial f(\bar x)$ be given.
Then we have
$$
\|\xi\| = \delta^{-1}\sup_{\|y\|<\delta} \xi(y)
\leq \delta^{-1}\sup_{\|y\|<\delta} (f(\bar x+y)-f(\bar x))
\leq \delta^{-1} 1 = \delta^{-1}.
$$
Therefore $\partial f(\bar x)$ is bounded.

Comment: thanks, that answers the question. Check the related bounty question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2792722/continuity-of-support-functionals